# How to make a parent div the same height as its first child?

Tags: html, css, position

Here's a picture:

[image: picture]!

My `div2` and `div3` contain dynamic content, such that their heights will be different each time. `div2` will always be much shorter than `div3` though.

I am looking for a way to force the height of `div3` to be that of `div2`'s, and then for `div1` to neatly contain them both, so the result should look like this:

[image]

But I'm not sure how to do this. Any advice?

Made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q93uvgcs/

Comment: please share your markup.

Comment: please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show us in code what you've tried

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted so much? I didn't initially share a fiddle because I wasn't sure if it was necessary because of how simple the markup was.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.div1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: fit-content(0);
  border: 1px solid;
}

.div2 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.div3 {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </div>
  <div class="div3">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </div>
</div>
```

You can use `display:grid` layout to achieve what you would like to do. On the parent setting columns to 1fr each, will fit them in the container horizontally, and setting fit-content(0) for rows, will set first's height to it's content, thus forcing the other one comply with the rule.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue unfortunately. The height of div2 should be fit-content.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Right now div2's height should be the defining height for div3.

Comment: Ah, CSS grid. Never used that before (nor not sure if I can even support it). This is close, but I still need div1 to fit the children (such that all 3 of their heights are basically the same).

Comment: Also, I noticed that div3 is overflowing outside the border of div1.